# Can I transform the Viterbi score from tensorflow into a probability?

Tags: tensorflow, conditional-random-field, viterbi-algorithm

I understand the Viterbi algorithm as it is explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm)

However, the [TensorFlow implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25c197e02393bd44f50079945409009dd4d434f8/tensorflow/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py#L335) is different:

```
  def viterbi_decode(score, transition_params):
  """Decode the highest scoring sequence of tags outside of TensorFlow.
  This should only be used at test time.
  Args:
    score: A [seq_len, num_tags] matrix of unary potentials.
    transition_params: A [num_tags, num_tags] matrix of binary potentials.
  Returns:
    viterbi: A [seq_len] list of integers containing the highest scoring tag
        indices.
    viterbi_score: A float containing the score for the Viterbi sequence.
  """
  trellis = np.zeros_like(score)
  backpointers = np.zeros_like(score, dtype=np.int32)
  trellis[0] = score[0]

  for t in range(1, score.shape[0]):
    v = np.expand_dims(trellis[t - 1], 1) + transition_params
    trellis[t] = score[t] + np.max(v, 0)
    backpointers[t] = np.argmax(v, 0)

  viterbi = [np.argmax(trellis[-1])]
  for bp in reversed(backpointers[1:]):
    viterbi.append(bp[viterbi[-1]])
  viterbi.reverse()

  viterbi_score = np.max(trellis[-1])
  return viterbi, viterbi_score
```

In the "traditional" Viterbi algorithm we basically keep multiplying probabilities and take the maximum. But the Viterbi score of Tensorflow is consistently greater than 1 and increases with sequence length.

1. Where is the Tensorflow implementation coming from?
2. How can the Viterbi score retrieved by Tensorflow be consistently >1 and increase with the sequence length?
3. **Is there a way of transforming the TensorFlow Viterbi score into a probability?** I want to compare the confidence of several sequence predictions in a Deep Learning architecture whose final layer is a CRF.

Comment: Sorry I dropped on this for a couple of months. Your answer is excellent. I learnt a lot! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable, and fortunately the code to do it is already written.

Bear in mind that the Viterbi algorithm on a CRF uses potentials, not probabilities. These are not required to sum to 1. The Wikipedia article's language is tailored to Viterbi on an HMM, so it keeps talking about probabilities.

---

> Where is the Tensorflow implementation coming from?

It's doing the familiar Viterbi algorithm, but working with log-potentials instead of potentials. Normally the two key operations in the Viterbi algorithm are $(\max, \times)$. In log-space, these become $(\max, +)$.

---

> How can the Viterbi score retrieved by Tensorflow be consistently >1 and increase with the sequence length?

This ties back to the log-space idea. If we were working with probabilities, they would be consistently < 1 and decrease with the sequence length. But log-potentials can be any real number, and they keep getting added together. It seems that yours are non-negative.

---

> Is there a way of transforming the TensorFlow Viterbi score into a probability?

Yes, certainly! You'll have to do a bit of extra work to get it, using the `crf_log_norm` function.

Remember that we use the Viterbi algorithm to find the highest-probability sequence $y^* = \arg\min_{y} p(y \mid x)$. But it does this by finding the sequence with the highest *unnormalized* probability $u(y \mid x)$—the 'Viterbi score' you got is the log of this. The relationship is that $p(y \mid x) = \frac{u(y \mid x)}{Z(x)}$. The Viterbi algorithm doesn't bother computing the normalizing constant $Z(x) = \sum_{y'} u(y' \mid x)$.

You're interested in $p(y^* \mid x)$. You already have $\log u(y^* \mid x)$. And there's a function in that library called `crf_log_norm` to compute $\log Z(x)$. All that remains is to compute the difference and then exponentiate.

\begin{align}
\log p(y^* \mid x) &= \log u(y^* \mid x) - \log Z(x) \\
p(y^* \mid x) &= \frac{u(y^* \mid x)}{Z(x)}
\end{align}

---

Just a reminder, though, computing $Z(x)$ with the forward algorithm is somewhat expensive: $O(nk^2)$ for $n$ tokens and $k$ possible states at each position. If you're comparing multiple possible taggings for one sequence, try to only compute $Z(x)$ once.